# I want to show a empty message if one of my list fragment goes empty

Tags: android, android-listview, fragment, empty-list

The empty text is showing even if the list is available .
I am tired finding the solution every where but nothing work for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.cervo.222.view.ViewSwitcher xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="No Details found" />
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</com.cervo.222.view.ViewSwitcher>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
Create 2 views. First view is a TextView with the empty list message . Keep this TextView hidden initially (Visibility GONE). Second view is your Listview. Keep it visible. IN your onCreate or any appropriate method is activity or Fragment when you find that there is  no data for List then make your ListView hidden and TextView visible.

Comment: In general - it works, but why not go the straight way by using 'setEmptyView' method? In this case Android will perform all those visibility manipulations for you.

Comment: The problem I found with that is when initially the listView loads it is empty by default and so the view in setEmptyView shows up. You probably use a loader or asynchtask or something to load data for placing in the list. The delay in data loading and the list population causes a split second flicker in the view which you set as empty view in ListView. That view shows and quickly goes out while the list loads. That was annoying for me.

Comment: Usually, I create a Listview in OnCreate(), and populate an adapter in OnResume() - and never faced the problem you are talking about. Maybe, because I populate an adapter from local DB, not with remote request results.

Comment: Yes. Sooner the adapter fills up sooner the `setEmptyView` vanishes. Mine was from remote REST WS call. In the end I stick to the way i said about above. It one less things to worry about when working with Android.